# In "You did me wrong", is "wrong" an adverb or some other part of speech instead?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, indirect-objects, ditransitivity

Consider:

> You did me wrong.

In that sentence, is *wrong* an adverb or some other part of speech? I don’t understand the syntactic construction being used here.

Comment: The other way to say this is 'You wronged me', where 'wronged' is clearly a verb.One may also say 'You did wrongfully towards me' where 'wrongfully' is clearly an adverb.

Comment: Some verbs take adjectives - *I feel good* is not the same as *I feel well*; *he acted bad* is not the same as *he acted badly*. *To do right* and *to do wrong* are similar, I would think, so in *you did wrong by me* or *you did me wrong* I would say *wrong* is an adjective.

Comment: @Minty If *wrong* were an adjective here, then it could be negated by *not*, but the resulting sentence is ungrammatical: *“You did me **ᕯnot** wrong.”* Instead, the correctly negated sentence is *“You did me **no** wrong”*, proving  beyond doubt that *wrong* can only be a noun not an adjective here.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that seems reasonable, but then why doesn't it need an article? Could it be that *you did me no wrong* is actually the negation of *you did me a wrong*, which is obviously very close in meaning to *you did me wrong*, but may not be the same syntactically?

Comment: ... well maybe it's just a mass noun. Doesn't feel like one though. I can see that *you did us proud* is different, but I can't make my mind up how different.

Comment: ... the point being that although *proud* is obviously an adjective and *you did us no proud* does not work, *you did us not proud* is no less strange than *you did us not wrong*.

Answer (score 5):

Like Toothrot, I would consider this use of *wrong* to be a noun. For at least some speakers, it can be negated with *no*, as "You did me no wrong" (e.g. in some translations of [Galatians 4:12](https://biblehub.com/esv/galatians/4-12.htm)). If *wrong* were an adjective or adverb in this sentence, we wouldn't expect this kind of negation to be possible.

Similarly structured expressions (although they have different meanings) are "to do one good" and "[to do one harm](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461101/is-expression-it-does-us-no-harm-grammatically-correct)".

There was a previous question asking about why people say "to do one wrong": [The grammatical strangeness of "done me wrong" and "did me service"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18769/the-grammatical-strangeness-of-done-me-wrong-and-did-me-service)

Comment: I feel that this answer and those you linked to answer stand to benefit greatly by first citing [OED sense 3 of *do*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56228) (and probably also subsense 3a), along with the note there that explains the OE-dative / ModE-indirect object versus the OE-accusative / ModE-direct object.

Comment: The note I'm referring to is: Originally with the recipient or person affected as indirect object (in Old  English in the dative), and that which is imparted or caused as direct
object (in Old English in the accusative): e.g. ‘it did him credit’. In
later use also with *to* and prepositional object: e.g. ‘it did credit to his
good sense’.  The original sense here appears to have been that of putting
(or bestowing) something to a person, and therefore closely related to
sense 1, in which a person is put to or into something.

Comment: And here are **do** senses 3 and 3a: 3. *transitive.* To bestow, impart, grant, render, give (a thing to a person); to cause to befall or come.  a. To impart to, bring upon (a person, etc.) some affecting quality or condition; to bestow, confer, inflict; to cause (a person) by one's action to have (something). In later use, associated more closely with the notion of performance, as in sense 4, e.g. *to do (a person) a service*, to perform some action that is of service to (a person).

Answer (score 4):

*wrong* is here a noun, or, if you will, an adjective used as a noun.

> You did (unto) me (a) wrong.